# How to display the logs of a VM on ELK stack which is running on another VM?

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elk

-ELK is running on localhost & successfully getting logs.

-Both VM's are on same server.

-OS on both VM'S is Ubuntu 18-04 LTS.

Comment: Did you setup filebeat on the client? I don't think you did the complete setup.

Comment: yes i have configured filebeat on client vm.
what i need to do in filebeat.yml in order to sends its logs to elk-server VM?

Comment: Not a fun thing, but follow all these steps and it should work, https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/how-to-setup-elk-logstash-as-centralized-log-management-server/

Answer (score 0):

I have a testing environment for my ELK stack build in Vagrant. I avoid the service-discovery problem by using static IP addresses for the VMs and configuring those as part of the Logstash/Filebeat config. If you are doing:

```
Filebeat --> [network] --> Logstash (beats {} input) --> Elasticsearch
```

Make sure the `beats {}` input is listening on something other than localhost.

If you are doing:

```
Filebeat --> [network] --> Elasticsearch
```

You will need to set up elasticsearch.yml to listen on the VM's interface rather than localhost.